# Cobol substrings; taking a 4 character string and taking the inside 2 characters

Tags: string, substring, cobol

I have been stuck on this issue for a while now. Help would be much appreciated.

I have a 4 digit number read in from a file and I need to take the inside 2 digits.
I thought that reading the number in as a string would be a good idea, then take the the middle two digits in a substring and use the numval function to convert them back. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to obtain the inside two characters.

Ex.
   I have the number 5465, I want to get 46.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208111/substring-for-a-string-literal-in-cobol

Comment: My COBOL is rusty but apart from the above the other way would be to have a record that contains two PIC 9(2) data types.

Answer (score 5):

What Keith Thompson proposes will work fine.  You might want to check that I > 0 and J > 0.  That wouldn't be a problem if you know 1000 <= I <= 9999 always.

IBM Enterprise COBOL includes a [MOD function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pdthelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rlinfmod.htm), which may or may not be available with your compiler.

I think you could also do the following...

```
01  A-GROUP.
    05  A-NUMBER PIC 9999 VALUE ZEROES.
    05  A-STRING REDEFINES A-NUMBER.
        10  FILLER PIC X.
        10  THE-MIDDLE-TWO-DIGITS PIC XX.
        10  FILLER PIC X.

MOVE your-number TO A-NUMBER.
```

This should work whether your-number is defined as COMP or COMP-3, provided 0 <= your-number <= 9999.

Comment: For clarity and correctness, I changed "PIC X" to "FILLER PIC X". Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: The "FILLER" hasn't been required, at least in mainframe COBOL, since 1985.

Answer (score 5):

You can use reference modification.  Consider the following:

```
1 WS-MY-FIELD Pic X(4).
1 WS-TGT-FIELD Pic X(2).
...
Move WS-MY-FIELD (2:2) to WS-TGT-FIELD
```

The first number indicates the start position (1 based) and the second number indicates the length.

Answer (score 3):

If you have it as a number rather than as a string, you can do it arithmetically.  Given that `I` is `5465`, and you want to store `46` in `J`:

```
DIVIDE I BY 10 GIVING J.
DIVIDE J BY 100 GIVING ignored REMAINDER J.
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm answering a COBOL question. 8-)} And if there's a cleaner way to compute a remainder (`mod` or `%` operator in some other languages), I'd be interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
01  a-long-piece-of-data.
    05  the-first-character pic x.
    05  the-two-characters-we-want pic xx.
    05  the-last-character pic x.

01  a-short-piece-of-data pic xx.
01  filler redefines a-short-piece-of-data.
    05  a-short-unsigned-number pic 99.

MOVE the-two-characters-we-want TO a-short-piece-of-data
MOVE/ADD/COMPUTE/whatever a-short-unsigned-number
```

or
    MOVE a-short-piece-of-data TO wherever

Have a signed number and want to retain the sign?

```
01  a-long-number PIC S9(4).
01  FILLER REDEFINES a-long-number.
    05  FILLER PIC X.
    05  an-integer-with-one-decimal-place PIC S99V9.

01  a-short-number-no-decimals PIC S99.

MOVE an-integer-with-one-decimal-place TO a-short-number-no-decimals
```